# Remove part of a JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here is the JSON returned from my Server.

```
"[{"description":"A user","name":"test","type":"user"}]"
```

I want to remove the outer double quates. Which means I want the JSON as

```
[{"description":"A user","name":"test","type":"user"}]
```

How can I do this? Please help.

Comment: If it has quotes around it like that, it is a string of JSON and not JSON.

Comment: if your server is actually sending those outer double quotes, it's not legal JSON...

Comment: @Quentin Thank you all. So if this is not a proper JSON, how do I convert this string of JSON to real JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the response from the server is not valid JSON you have to request it as text, fix it, and parse it as JSON. Use `dataType: 'text'` in your options in the [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call.

Use the `substr` method to cut of the first and last character:

```
data = data.substr(1, data.length - 2);
```

Then you can parse the JSON:

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Comment: This is the answer worked for me. thanks sir.. Anyway special thanks to @quentin Thank you all.

Answer (score 4):

You want to turn the JSON into JS objects right? If so, you would do `JSON.parse(json)`. If you need IE7 support, you have to include a polyfill for JSON as it's not supported in IE7<.

You can get the current JSON polyfill here: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Comment: The question is about removing quotes around a JSON text, not parsing JSON.

Comment: yeah after double checking the question I was also not 100% sure if the answer fits the wanted

Answer (score 2):

To strip the first and last character from a string:

```
var fixed_string = string.substring(1, string.length - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

var str =  '[{"description":"A user","name":"test","type":"user"}]';

var data = (new Function( "return " +s))();
console.log(f);

Answer (score 0):

In your case response from server is a json string you have to convert it to json object

```
var str = '[{"description":"A user","name":"test","type":"user"}]'; 
str = eval('('+str+')');
console.log(str[0].name) //this will give test
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You should really NOT use eval. Especially not if the evaluated content is dynamic and comes from the server side. If you'd think of a use case where people can submit thinks and the server sends such data to the client, which "eval"s it, you'll run into situations, where you will execute malicious code.